# Sylvanie DVD/Tablet combo Ubuntu Kernel 3.0.36+

Tags: dvd, tablet, volume-control

I have a Sylvania Tablet with integrated portable DVD player.  The volume when playing a DVD is very low and can't be heard if there's any background noise in the room.  Any ideas on how I can change this?  The regular volume control goes up to vol 16, but that is not high enough.

Unit details:
Model SLTDV9200.
The kernel version 3.0.36+ yflan@ubuntu-system-product-name #368
Build number SLTDV9200-eng 4.4.4 KTU85Q eng.gqsu.20150505.183041 test-keys

Thanks for your help.